# Selenium webdriver java - upload file with phantomjs driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, ghostdriver

I am running a selenium webdriver script headless using Phantomjs Driver. I am having issues uploading a file though since on a normal browser (firefox or chrome) it would pop up the OS dialog box that would allow me to locate the file in my machine and upload it.
How to do that with the ghostDriver (Phantomjs Driver)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always identify & interact with elements of type "file" when uploads are concerned. This would solve your issue of pop ups.

Ex: In my application, upload related elements have the below DOM -

```
<a id="uploadFileButtonLink" class="uploadFileButtonLink" href="javascript:void(0)" data-uidsfdc="3" style="display: none;">Upload a file</a>
<input id="multiFileInput" class="multifile-upload-input-button" type="file" name="chatterFile_upload" multiple="multiple"/>
<input id="multiUploadBtn" class="btnImportant" type="button" value="Upload Files"/>
```

In this case, you can use sendKeys method to "multiFileInput" which is of type "file".
This way it would work for all FF, Chrome & also headless browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However, my application is written in extjs (nested spans and divs). And there is no text area next to the upload button. Would appreciate other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and have posted a question for the same. PhantomJS hangs up when using sendKeys() method.

They have an issue logged here - https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10993

One of the comments on the issue stated that the below statement worked -

```
(PhantomJSDriver) driver.executePhantomJS("var page = this; page.uploadFile('input[type=file]', 'path to file');");
```

You may try the above solution, but it may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me with uploading if 'multiple' attribute was set:

```
protected void uploadFile(CharSequence... keys) {
    if (((WrapsDriver) driver).getWrappedDriver() instanceof PhantomJSDriver) {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(keys.length);
        for (int index = 0; index < keys.length; index++) {
            s.append(keys[index].toString());
        }
        ((PhantomJSDriver) ((WrapsDriver) driver).getWrappedDriver()).executePhantomJS(
                String.format("var page = this; page.uploadFile(arguments[0], '%s');", s.toString()), getElement());
    } else {
        getElement().sendKeys(keys);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var webPage = require('webpage');   
var page = webPage.create();
page.uploadFile('input[name=image]', '/path/to/some/photo.jpg');
```

in the new version of phantomjs, you can upload file like this
[uploadfile](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/upload-file.html)